# Error when using QString in QMetaObject::invokeMethod

Tags: c++, qt

Error:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘QArgument<QString>::QArgument(
    const char [8],
   __gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >, 
   std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >::value_type&)’
```

At:

```
QMetaObject::invokeMethod(
    mReceiver, 
    "setname", 
    Qt::QueuedConnection, 
    Q_ARG(QString, "test"));
```

Here is the error that I am facing when using QString as the parameter of `Q_ARG()` in `QMetaObject::invokeMethod`. So may I know is there any solution to this problem?

Comment: Try to invoke the constructor explicitly like this: QString("test")

Comment: Please provide a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1):

I found that we can directly convert the string to QString in Q_ARG() to prevent this error:

```
QMetaObject::invokeMethod(
    mReceiver, 
    "setname", 
    Qt::QueuedConnection, 
    Q_ARG(QString, QString::fromStdString("test")));
```